# Understanding a part in a solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I was reading this question [Showing this to $1 \leq p < \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441877/showing-this-to-1-leq-p-infty/3444802#3444802) ,  here on this site.

**But I did not understand this part (in the third solution mentioned there given by @mechanodroid):**

" Now notice that for large enough $t_0 \ge 1$ we have $t \ge t_0 \implies \ln t \le \sqrt[2p]{t}$ so the above integral can be bounded by
$$\int_1^{t_0}\frac{(\ln t)^p}{t^2}\,dt + \int_{t_0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} < +\infty$$
which is finite since $\frac{(\ln t)^p}{t^2}$ is bounded on $[1,t_0]$ and $t \mapsto \frac1{t^{3/2}}$ is integrable on $[1, +\infty)$."

Could anyone clarify this part for me, please?

2- Also for the second solution given by @Awegan, I can see a typo in $p$ and $q$, the powers of $L$, am I correct?

3- Also, is there an alternative proof (detailed) for the question given in the link I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_1^{t_0}\frac{(\ln t)^p}{t^2}\,dt + \int_{t_0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{3/2}} < +\infty$$

Since the integrand of the left hand integral is bounded, then
$$\int_1^{t_0}\frac{(\ln t)^p}{t^2}dt\leq M(t_0-1),$$
where $M$ is the bound ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities)). Clearly this is finite.

For the right hand integral, just evaluate it, e.g.

$$\int_{t_0}^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{3/2}}dt=\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{t}}\right]_{t_0}^{+\infty}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{t_0}},$$
which is also finite.

The sum of two finite numbers gives a finite number, so by definition of $L^p$ spaces $f\in L^p(0,1]$.

---

In answer to your comment, here's a plot of $\log t$ (in blue) and $t^{1/(2p)}$ for $p=1.4$, for example. As you can see, $t_0\approx 35$ in this case, after which the inequality holds true for $t\geq t_0$. This always happens for some $t_0$ value.

[image]

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: @Mathstupid re (2) I think you may be right, there is a typo, check out this for comparison: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390227/proving-that-lp-subset-lq-when-1-le-q-le-p

Comment: And why we are assuming "for large enough $t_0 \ge 1$" ?

Comment: Why "$\ln t \le \sqrt[2p]{t}$"?

Comment: Is there any mathematical proof for my last question other than the drawing?

Comment: @Mathstupid yes, check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial

Comment: why the integrand of the left hand integral is bounded?

Comment: Is this because it is a continuous function (as it is a rational function of a continuous ln function in the numerator and a polynomial (continuous) in the denominator) on a closed interval  ?

Comment: @Mathstupid pretty much, yes. I mean $t>1$ so $\ln t$ behaves nicely, so that you get a continuous function $(\ln t)^p/t^2$, so since we consider integrating over $(1,t_0)$ then there must be some maximum $M$ of that function in $(1,t_0)$.